# Importing Wand in Python Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-import, wand, magickwand

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, Python and have never used imported anything in Python before.
My Ubuntu system has Python2.7, 3 and 3.4 installed. I'm trying to start working with Wand for an assignment.
Using this [documentation](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/index.html) from Wand website I installed MagickWand and Wand using (sudo)

```
$ apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
$ pip install Wand
```

Now when I try to run the Python script, error-

```
Traceback (most recent call): 
File "PTI.PY", line 2, in <module>
    from wand.image import Image
ImportError: No module named wand.image
```

This looks a path or some other configuration error to me, how do I fix this? I looked another similar question in which there was one answer (not marked as solution though) which suggested using virtualenv butI'm not sure if I should try that method. Any help is appreciated.

Edit- Since I cant post a comment yet, I did not use sudo with "pip install Wand" and "pip3 install Wand" says "The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python3-pip"

Edit 2- So I tried installing using pip3 and pip again, failed with the error, "could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wand': Permission denied" and realized that Wand was never configured.

So my question now is, how to provide correct permissions? Or should I look into the virtualenv method.

Comment: module didn't install correctly ... for install a package using pip don't use `sudo`. also you can test `pip3 install Wand`

Answer (score 4):

The issue will be resolved with the below installation:

```
$ apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
$ pip install Wand
```

Also, please refer the updated version of wand:
[wand installation](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.3/)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install python-wand
```

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out myself, basically the error- "could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wand': Permission denied" was the problem here. 
I simply reinstalled Wand by using

```
sudo pip install Wand
```